# QScrollArea within QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a QDialog of size 720x480. I added 100 QLabels on it, and after that I created a QScrollArea, which has as widget the QDialog:

```
QDialog *window = new QDialog;
window->setWindowTitle("My Dialog");
window->setFixedSize(720, 480);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(window);
    label->setText(QString::number(i));
    label->move(10, i * 100);
}
QScrollArea area;
area.setWidget(window);
window->exec();
```

But the result is not that expected (like the vertical scrollbar to appear and to work properly ).

Answer (score 0):

Your `window` has fixed height (to 480) and you place labels far beyond this size (last one will be placed at position 10, 9900).

You need to change your `window`'s size.

Comment: You also need to call `area.show()` before `window->exec();` It's also weird in your program that you call exec on window which is not a top one. It would be better if you change it.